# Discriminating items of filtered array of generic values in generic class

Tags: typescript, generics

I know that the question may be not too clear, but it's very difficult to phrase questions and find answers to such abstract cases, and I honestly don't know how to put it better.

I have the following code:

```
enum TagType {
    SIMPLE = 'simple',
    COLLECTOR = 'collector',
}

interface Tag {
    type: TagType,
}

interface SimpleTag extends Tag {
    type: TagType.SIMPLE,
}

interface CollectorTag extends Tag {
    type: TagType.COLLECTOR,
}

interface ServiceDefinition<T extends Tag> {
    tags: T[],
}

// This works.
const definition: ServiceDefinition<Tag> = {tags: []};
const collectorTags: CollectorTag[] = definition.tags.filter((t: Tag): t is CollectorTag => t.type === TagType.COLLECTOR);

// This doesn't work.
class CollectorDefinitionProcessor <T extends Tag> {
    process(definition: ServiceDefinition<T>): void {
        const collectorTags: CollectorTag[] = definition.tags.filter((t: T): t is CollectorTag => t.type === TagType.COLLECTOR);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgcxgTwA7CgbwFBT1AZQEkBZABQBkBRKAXigHIBnASwlQBtgGAaXfAMIB5CtQEwhAJTqMAxgHsOXWQBd5AJ17YAvtmwsQK4OoBmcWRngIs-PCrTAAXLEQp0fXfsPGzFwm05gKyhgAA8jEAATJhdrHHwoe3RnKzdgADpicmoPPQMjU3MMAUVlNXVgsIjo2JsEpKdYtPThUSpxKVyvAt8MAmMANxYLABFgEwMWFRZ5EAAeGBDw0BqrAD46-BVEJhSAbQBdLoB6Y9gACxYYgHcNAGsmdOwFECYVKEjxyenZ5371IajL4gKYzebrGSYbYIXZQQ7aADcz1mbygCiUwFUGissJKGKxFUQhxknwmIJ%20IHS0MeEw4BQAFPSVClEABKZzvK5QPFlbGIOgbFRUhx0Wj0VIOFoiMQSSSspHYU4XLmReTAJggBjvW7qO5PWQcOBMGI8zHlMZk0GzMjqeQWY0aKALJbVGIQ%20L4VC2%201Memk75gv6DYbAC0B2YLNbsqADeQsSKbBJ4F6o9G8wkw5ymglWYn0f3ksFUnbpWkMpkpaOck2lM186y0QXC9Ci8WuSWtGVSeW2KC6XRAA)

Why code in the class is wrong? How can we discriminate items of this array in the generic class like the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `definition.tags` can contain all types of tags defined in the enum.
You could explicitly cast the CollectorTags to your desired type like this:

```
class CollectorDefinitionProcessor<T extends Tag> {
  process(definition: ServiceDefinition<T>): void {
    const collectorTags: CollectorTag[] = definition.tags.filter(
      (t: T) => t.type === TagType.COLLECTOR
    ) as CollectorTag[]
  }
}
```

Comment: But the same generic type is used in the filter, so any idea why Typescript cannot discriminate the enum values there? Is it a bug or there is a good reason for it?

Comment: I don't think Typescript can infer that it's of type `CollectorTag` just because it is the only one with `type: TagType.COLLECTOR`. There might be other Tags with `type: TagType.COLLECTOR` elsewhere (even in other files, although in your case there aren't). Accounting for all these possibilities would be way too complicated on a TS side, that's why I don't think this is a bug.